# Regex Grouping behaves abnormally

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I need to recognize digits like `xxx.xxx` First digit is optional and it can be `0` or `1`. Second one also is optional and it can be `0` to `9`. And the third one should be `0` to `9`.

So i used Regex like `([0|1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\\.\\1`. But i'm seeing unexpected behaviors

Here is my code,

```
package HelloWorld;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Practice 
{
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String sample;
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            sample = br.readLine();
            if(Pattern.matches(MyRegex.pattern,sample))
            {
                System.out.println("true");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("false");
            }
        }
    }
}
class MyRegex
{
    public static String pattern = "([0|1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\\.\\1";
}
```

For inputs,

```
000.12  => false
000.00  => false
000.000 => true
23.23   => trie
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please create a proper [mcve] (including all code necessary to reproduce the issue).

Comment: The regex works as per your specs. The first `xxx` must be equal to the second `xxx` to match.

Comment: What do you think `\\1` does? It does **not repeat** the whole regex. It only repeats what you previously captured. That's why it only allows repetitions like `23.23` since the second part is equal to the first.

Comment: `[0|1]` should probably be `[01]`

Comment: Thanks @Zabuza Can you please say how to ensure the entire thing is checked again. Should i need to retype the content again to match it?

Comment: Yes, retype it. Alternatively save it inside a `String` and repeat it through `part + part`, string concatenation.

Comment: @Previnkumar other languages allow recursion in regex. Unfortunately, Java is not one of those languages, so as Zabuza mentioned, you'll have to retype the subpattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\\1` command does **not repeat** the regex inside the group. It only repeats what text you previously captured.

So it is **not equivalent** to the regex

```
([0|1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\\.([0|1]?[0-9]?[0-9])
```

That's why it only allows repetitions like `23.23` since the second part is equal to the first.

If you want repetitions of the regex you will need to retype it. Either explicit or implicit like

```
String part = "([0|1]?[0-9]?[0-9])";
String pattern = part + "\\." + part;
```

---

Note that with `[0|1]` you probably meant `[01]`. Everything inside `[...]` is already interpreted as **set**.

If you use `[0|1]` you actually match the characters `0`, `1` **and** the character `|`. So your pattern would match inputs likes

```
|13.|13 // Matches
```

There are multiple sites to test regex, with explanation, like *regex101*. Here's your example [regex101/r/f1ytVE](https://regex101.com/r/f1ytVE/1).